# How to append list values to list of dictionary with the same length?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, I have a list of 3 values:

```
['California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut']
```

How to append the values to list of dictionary with the same list length?

```
[{'abbrev': 'CA', 'slug': 'ca'}, {'abbrev': 'CO', 'slug': 'co'}, {'abbrev': 'CT', 'slug': 'ct'}]
```

In the result I need the list of dictionaries as below

```
[{'title':'California', 'abbrev': 'CA', 'slug': 'ca'}, {'title':'Colorado', 'abbrev': 'CO', 'slug': 'co'}, {'title': 'Connecticut', 'abbrev': 'CT', 'slug': 'ct'}]
```

Thanks!

Comment: The list length is the same, but is the state order guaranteed to be the same?

Comment: What have you tried, and what *specific* problem(s) are you having with it?

Comment: Yes the state order is the same (manually edited)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate in parallel over both lists:

```
states = ['California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut']
ds = [{'abbrev': 'CA', 'slug': 'ca'}, {'abbrev': 'CO', 'slug': 'co'}, {'abbrev': 'CT', 'slug': 'ct'}]

for title, d in zip(states, ds):
    d['title'] = title
```

**Output**

```
[{'abbrev': 'CA', 'slug': 'ca', 'title': 'California'}, {'abbrev': 'CO', 'slug': 'co', 'title': 'Colorado'}, {'abbrev': 'CT', 'slug': 'ct', 'title': 'Connecticut'}]
```

Comment: A very elegant way! Thanks!

Comment: @dtar Glad I could help!

Comment: @dtar if it solves your question don't forget to mark it as an answer so we know you aren't still looking for an answer. It also helps out the person who answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

Using `update` you can add a key with a value to a dictionary, however, it will be appended at the end.

```
b = [{'abbrev': 'CA', 'slug': 'ca'}, {'abbrev': 'CO', 'slug': 'co'}, {'abbrev': 'CT', 'slug': 'ct'}]
a = ['California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut']
for i in range(len(a)):
    b[i].update({'title':a[i]})
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[{'abbrev': 'CA', 'slug': 'ca', 'title': 'California'}, {'abbrev': 'CO', 'slug': 'co', 'title': 'Colorado'}, {'abbrev': 'CT', 'slug': 'ct', 'title': 'Connecticut'}]
```

Comment: Aren't the contents of dictionaries unordered?

Comment: @ScottHunter not in 3.6+ (they are insertion ordered). Plus he is using a list of dicts.

Comment: I am trying to replicate exactly OP's desired output.

Comment: How does "using a list of dicts" enter into it?

Comment: Why is the answer getting upvotes, is `zip` better in performance than `update` when dealing with dictionaries? Or is my answer wrong somewhere? Not asking for the votes specifically, but I always thought `update` was they way to go when wanting to add key-values to a dictionary.

Comment: @CeliusStingher zip is a cleaner solution than using indices. Not that this answer is bad, it is just `zip` is slightly cleaner (at least for most people). Also update should only really be used for updating multiple keys. For just changing one key it is excise.

Comment: I understand, thanks, I will read the documentation in depth.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
states = ['California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut']
ds = [{'abbrev': 'CA', 'slug': 'ca'}, {'abbrev': 'CO', 'slug': 'co'}, {'abbrev': 'CT', 'slug': 'ct'}]
title = dict(zip(states, ds))
title
```

Output:

```
{'California': {'abbrev': 'CA', 'slug': 'ca'},
 'Colorado': {'abbrev': 'CO', 'slug': 'co'},
 'Connecticut': {'abbrev': 'CT', 'slug': 'ct'}}
```